# How can I use geoserver's user management for my application

Tags: java, authentication, geoserver, user-management

I'm developing a gis application with java. My layers are in [geoserver](http://geoserver.org). Layers have different permissions, some layers have public permissions and some of them have private permissions. for private layers, Users must log in to my application that my application's users and [geoserver](http://geoserver.org)'s users are one.
In the other words, I want to use [geoserver](http://geoserver.org)'s user management in my application to log in users like **geoexplorer**.

How do I implement this issue? How do users login to my application and can read geoserver's layers directly?

Answer (score 2):

Geoserver has CAS plugin , you should enable CAS for geoserver and implement CAS client in your application for SSO, then each application can use current user for authorization purpose, geoserver automatically do that.

Useful links:
http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/geoserver-and-cas/
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/tutorials/cas/index.html